# Eclipse - Android - Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Good morning,

I have installed Eclipse and the plug in Android ADT.
I have created a new android project which is the classical :

```
package com.example.test_android_2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

But when I run this code, there are the following things in the console window :

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Invalid layout of preloaded class: use -XX:+TraceClassLoading to see the    origin of the problem class
```

There are no errors in the error window and nothing is happening. My connected device is not detected.

When i click on "Run as", there is no item (only "none applicable")

There is a problem of installation of Eclipse or ADT Android ?

Can you help me please ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, and I think the best solutions as the following.
First, the versions that you want work with must be installed by SDK Manager.
Second,once you have installed the versions, then go to the run configuration and set the Android project that you have created. Third, 
make sure that the SDK verison is the same as the target SDK as well as the Compile. From point of view if you are beginner with Android, I recommend you to start with API 14(version 4).
Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Finally I used Android Studio to do my program and there is no more error. Thanks you for your help. Regards.